# The page doesn't reload facebook plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

Facebook script:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=856804484356308";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

script:

```
      function loadHome(){  
              $( ".scorrimentoslide" ).fadeIn("slow");
              //Ripristina il vecchio div dell'homepage in index.html 
              $('.sfondobianco').load(document.URL +  ' .sfondobianco');

      }
```

html:

```
    <div class="sfondobianco">
        <div class="menusinistra">
            <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Big-GYM/1567454133517054?fref=ts" data-height="100%" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Big-GYM/1567454133517054?fref=ts"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Big-GYM/1567454133517054?fref=ts">Big GYM</a></blockquote></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contenitoredestra">

        <div class="banner"> <img src="images/save.png" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"> </div>

        <div class="container marketing contenitore">.........
```

I put  (facebook script) at the bottom of the homepage.
If i change div:contenitoredestra when i load another page, the facebook div doesnt disappear.
But when i go back at the home, the div disappear. Why? What can i do? 
The site is http://hyp.altervista.org/index.html#

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use [FB.XFMBL.parse()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) right after adding plugins dynamically:

```
$('.sfondobianco').load(document.URL +  ' .sfondobianco', function() {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
});
```

Comment: So where? in load home? console said that FB is not defined

Comment: and of course AFTER loading the javascript sdk. check out the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3#loading